# How to insert values from one table into another table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to programming. So I have a page Where a security operator can assign users from the website to become operators when he type their ID from the input field tap. So my question is how to get the details for the user from my table named 'Customer' and insert it into my table named 'Operator' ? This is my code :

```
<div class='input_field'>
    <form action='SecOperator.php' method='POST'>
        <input type='text' name='text' class='text' placeholder='Enter the ID of the User'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='Press Register'>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
if (empty($_POST['text'])) {
    echo 'This field is empty';
} else {
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    include 'connect.php';
    $table  = 'customer';
    $table2 = 'operator';
    if (mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbName)) {


        $query = "INSERT INTO $table2(OperatorID,username,Operator_name,password)" . "SELECT CustomerID ,username,customer_name,password " . "FROM $table WHERE CustomerID = ?";

        if ($statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'i', $cusID);

            $queryresult = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            if ($queryresult === false) {
                echo 'There was a problem ' . mysqli_error($conn);
            } else {
                echo 'Insert' . '<br>';
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
        }

        $query = "UPDATE $table2 SET username = 'operator' WHERE OperatorID = ?";

        if ($statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'i', $opid);

            $queryresult = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            if ($queryresult === false) {
                mysqli_error($conn);
            } else {
                echo 'Update';
            }

        }
        mysqli_close($conn);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Firstly, do you know how to retrieve data from your database ? That's probably the first step.

Comment: @PHPnoob Yes I know that

Comment: You are using concatenation strangely but please describe what happens with this code. Looks like it should be close already.

Comment: @user3783243 The code is technically working but it's not effecting the tables in the database in any way for some reason

Comment: You have no `else` condition so perhaps the prepare fails and then fails silently? Add an `else` and some error reporting

Comment: You also can put static values in the `select` list and your `update` will not be needed, `SELECT CustomerID , 'operator', customer_name`

Comment: @user3783243 one thing I forgot to mention is that the 2 tables from the database have different name rows. Could this be the problem

Comment: Nope, it just writes to them based on their order.